# Retrosynthesis of spirocyclic compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

I have been trying to complete this retrosynthesis problem for a few days but can’t figure out how to get from Ester starting compound to a spirocyclic compound. I have tried removing the Ester but can’t figure out what best to replace it with.
I have access to any reagents and starting materials as long as the nominated substance is used.

[image: Retrosynthesis]

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Form the anion of your starting material ($\ce{NaOEt/EtOH}$ will do this nicely) and react with phenethyl bromide ($\ce{PhCH2CH2Br}$).

Step 2 - Add the product to hot polyphosphoric acid$\ce{^{[1]}}$ to cyclize it to the required product.

**Reference**

1. Cyclization of Aryl-Aliphatic Esters with Phosphorus Pentoxide in Phosphoric Acid by Richard C. Gilmore, *Journal of the American Chemical Society*, **1951**, 73 (12), 5879-5880, DOI: [10.1021/ja01156a521](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01156a521)